# C# how to call an as 400 stored procedure using oledb

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, db2, oledb, db2-400

Hi I am trying to call an as400 stored procedure using OleDB. Could you please post an example of how to do it cause I've been following some tutorials but not matter what I do I always get an Invalid Token Exception 
this is what I do

```
        OleDbCommand sp = new OleDbCommand("CALL NASVARWG.SP001(?,?,?,?,?) ", connectionDB);
            sp.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sp.Parameters.Add("P1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "ESANASTRIS";
            sp.Parameters["P1"].Size = 10;
            sp.Parameters["P1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sp.Parameters.Add("P2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "SAMNAS";
            sp.Parameters["P2"].Size = 10;
            sp.Parameters["P2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sp.Parameters.Add("P3", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox_Reparto.Text;
            sp.Parameters["P3"].Size = 6;
            sp.Parameters["P3"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sp.Parameters.Add("P4", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "we can do this";
            sp.Parameters["P4"].Size = 60;
            sp.Parameters["P4"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sp.Parameters.Add("P5", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Char).Value = "help";
            sp.Parameters["P5"].Size = 256;
            sp.Parameters["P5"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            sp.Prepare();
            sp.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the exception I get says "NASVARWG" is not a valid token. Why? that is the name of the library containing the procedure and the spelling is correct.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's quite a specific question, so I don't have an 100% sure answer for you, but probably, that is not the complete command you would use to call a stored procedure in AS 400. I found this online, does this help: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0007055.html

Comment: AS400 is a type of computer, not a data store. So what is the data store your trying to access DB2?

Comment: @Liam yeas I am trying to access  DB2

Comment: @Ale61268967  Which Db2 client name have you installed on your Windows workstation, and what is its version?

Comment: @mao I am using Iseries Access for Windows version 5

Answer (score 0):

A C# code with CommandType.StoredProcedure example :

```
// assume a DB2Connection conn
DB2Transaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
DB2Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
String procName = "INOUT_PARAM";
cmd.Transaction = trans;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = procName;
```

A C# code with CommandType.Text example :

```
// assume a DB2Connection conn
DB2Transaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
DB2Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
String procName = "INOUT_PARAM";
String procCall = "CALL INOUT_PARAM (@param1, @param2, @param3)";
cmd.Transaction = trans;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = procCall;

// Register input-output and output parameters for the DB2Command
cmd.Parameters.Add( new DB2Parameter("@param1", "Value1");
cmd.Parameters.Add( new DB2Parameter("@param2", "Value2");
DB2Parameter param3 = new DB2Parameter("@param3", IfxType.Integer);
param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add( param3 );

// Call the stored procedure
Console.WriteLine("  Call stored procedure named " + procName);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // Register input-output and output parameters for the DB2Command
    ...

    // Call the stored procedure
    Console.WriteLine("  Call stored procedure named " + procName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: but is it possible to achive the same thing using OleDB ? moreover where do I find the db2.dll ?!?

Comment: I havent found the solution for OleDB. `moreover where do I find the db2.dll ?!? ` You can put this in the very top of your program `using IBM.Data.DB2;`

Comment: I tried but it's not recognized :-( What Am I missing?!?

Comment: What is not recognized?

Comment: the IBM.Data.DB2 when I put "using IBM.Data.DB2" they are not found

Comment: This is used when you are using DB2 as DB. What DB are you using? SQL? Oracle?

Comment: sorry for the late of the answer, yeas as400 use DB2 as DB

Comment: Have you connect it?

Comment: yeas I have no problem connecting to the DB